# SQL Server query optimization for a example update query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

In my transaction table I have around 90Millions records.One column "time" has format like below. There is no order this format is maintained and its very random across this "time" columns.

```
 Time
----------
23:44:33
12:17 09
20 00 20
  :  :  
111913
```

I wanted to make/update this time format as:

```
    Time
   --------
   23:44:33
   12:17:09
   20:00:20
   21:12:00  
   11:19:13
```

I have written below query to update "Time" to get my desired results.

```
    Update [dbo].[table] 
   set [TIME] = '21:14:00'
   WHERE [TIME] = '  :  :  '


   Update [dbo].[table]
   set [time] = replace([TIME], ' ','')  
   WHERE [time]   like '[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]'

      Update [dbo].[table]
      set [time] = STUFF(STUFF([TIME],3,0,':'),6,0,':')
      WHERE [time] like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

Update [dbo].[table]
    set [time] = replace([time], ' ', ':')
    WHERE [time] like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]'
```

The above query is continuously getting executed and its taking very long time.

Is there any way to optimize this to get the desired results?

Please give a better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to do it with one run  but rather:

```
DECLARE @r INT;

WHILE @r > 0
BEGIN
   Update TOP (50000) [dbo].[table]
   set [time] = replace([TIME], ' ','')  
   WHERE [time]   like '[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]';

   SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
   -- when there is no rows left @@ROWCOUNT will be 0
END;
```

Also I would check database [recovery model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server) and control transaction log growth.

---

Adding index before update may help:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_dbo_table_time
  ON [dbo].[table] ([time] ASC) 
  WHERE [time] like '[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]';
```

Comment: You have only considered the time format:  [time] like '[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]' . What about other time format? should I do each time format individually? Also, it looks like the while loop will keep on running again and again as we are doing   SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT; is it that @@ROWCOUNT will be 0 once every row is updated with that condition?What is your thought on this?

Comment: @AskMe Of course you have to do it for every time format you need. So you will end up with 3 loops and 3 support indexes. As for ROWCOUNT after there will be no rows to update left it will be 0 and loop will end. **[Demo](http://rextester.com/CUYB49263)**

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to figure out all the different variations... Just take all values that don't fit the desired pattern and strip out all non numeric characters, leaving you with 6 numbers all in the proper positions. Form there it's just a matter of using the STUFF function to put the colons where they belong.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    TimeVal VARCHAR(20)
    );
INSERT #TestData (TimeVal) VALUES
    ('23:44:33'),
    ('12:17 09'),
    ('20 00 20'),
    ('  :  :  '),
    ('111913'),
    ('12:17'),
    ('12:   09'),
    ('  :17 09');

-- before values...
SELECT [Before] = td.TimeVal FROM #TestData td;

-- update problem values...
UPDATE td SET  
    td.TimeVal = CASE LEN(rr.TimeVal)
                    WHEN 6 THEN STUFF(STUFF(rr.TimeVal, 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':')
                    ELSE '21:12:00'
                END
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(td.TimeVal, ' ', ''), ':', '')) ) rr (TimeVal)
WHERE 
    td.TimeVal NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]';

-- after values...
SELECT [After] = td.TimeVal FROM #TestData td;
```

Before & after results...

```
Before
--------------------
23:44:33
12:17 09
20 00 20
  :  :  
111913
12:17
12:   09
  :17 09

After
--------------------
23:44:33
12:17:09
20:00:20
21:12:00
11:19:13
21:12:00
21:12:00
21:12:00
```

As far as how best to execute this against 90M rows... It tough to say w/o knowing more about your environment. What is the recovery model? What are you're server specs? How man nonclustered indexes include this column?
Get with you DBA, he/she will know better than anyone, how the database will handle the update... Plus, they are the one who will come for your head if you lock up the instance by filling log file and/or tempdb drives. You want them involved.

That said, I will agree with others who recommended breaking it up into chunks. When I have to do mass updates on large tables, I use a similar looping process and record the progress to a simple log table so that 1) I can track the progress while it's under way and 2) I know the last committed transaction set if I need to shut it down and later.

Something like the following...

```
-- create a log table to make it easy to know where you arw in the update process.
CREATE TABLE dbo.TimeValUpdate_LOG (
    BegID INT,
    EndID INT,
    RowsUpdated INT,
    BegTime DATETIME,
    EndTime DATETIME,
    SecsToComplete AS DATEDIFF(SECOND, BegTime, EndTime)
    );

-- update script...
DECLARE 
    @BegID INT = 0,
    @EndID INT = 500000,
    @BegTime DATETIME,
    @EndTime DATETIME;


WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.RealTable rt WHERE rt.PrimaryKey  > @BegID)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
        --===================================
        SET @BegTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
        INSERT dbo.TimeValUpdate_LOG (BegID, EndID, BegTime) VALUES (@BegID, @EndID, @BegTime);
        --=============================================================================

            -- update problem values...
            UPDATE rt SET  
                rt.TimeVal = CASE LEN(rr.TimeVal)
                                WHEN 6 THEN STUFF(STUFF(rr.TimeVal, 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':')
                                ELSE '21:12:00'
                            END
            FROM
                dbo.RealTable rt
                CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(rt.TimeVal, ' ', ''), ':', '')) ) rr (TimeVal)
            WHERE 
                rt.PrimaryKey >= @BegID
                AND rt.PrimaryKey < @EndID
                AND rt.TimeVal NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]';

        --=============================================================================
        UPDATE tul SET
            tul.RowsUpdated = @@ROWCOUNT,
            tul.EndTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        FROM 
            dbo.TimeValUpdate_LOG tul
        WHERE 
            tul.BegID = @BegID
            AND tul.EndID = @EndID;
        --===================================
        SET @BegID = @EndID + 1;
        SET @EndID = @BegID + 500000;
        --===================================
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

            DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT = ERROR_NUMBER();
            DECLARE @ErrorLine INT = ERROR_LINE();
            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
            DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
            DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

            PRINT 'Actual error number: ' + CAST(@ErrorNumber AS VARCHAR(10));
            PRINT 'Actual line number: ' + CAST(@ErrorLine AS VARCHAR(10));

            RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
    END CATCH;
END;
```

Comment: Where there is   :  :  I would like to update a default value as 21:12:00 ( not the blank) .Also, could you please give a small explanation about cross apply - how its working?

Comment: The cross apply takes the time value, strips spaces and colons from it and matches it to every row in the #TestData table.  So you have two columns, on that is unmodified and one that is stripped down.  I would only suggest that you change the ELSE '' to ELSE '21:12:00' and you have your default.  If you are doing this over 90 million rows I would do it in chunks to avoid table locks and log file explosion.  @lad2025 above had a good model to do it.

Comment: @AskMe - Are you asking what the CROSS APPLY is doing or how the CROSS APPLY operators works in general? If it's the former, **JM_7** is exactly correct. It's stripping out and spaces & semi-colons from the string. If the rest of your data has other non int characters, it should be expanded to strip those as well. If it's later, that's a far too large a topic for a few hundred characters... Here's are a couple of really good videos from Itzik Ben-Gan. There really are worth the time it takes to watch them https://youtu.be/-m426WYclz8 & https://youtu.be/goyWzAu-AA0

Comment: @AskMe - Mt answer has been updated to allow the default value and I added comments & code related to mass updates of large tables.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the query is continuously executing so I understand that you are correcting data inserted from another application that you can't change (if it's only a one-time job then follow any of the other answers, they have good suggestions for that).

In that case you could use a trigger so records get inserted in the correct format, I suppose that the table has a primary/unique key, which maybe is not the case for a table that just logs transactions:

```
create trigger trCorrectTime on [table] after insert
as
    update [table] set [time] = '21:14:00'
    from [table]
    join inserted on inserted.id=[table].id
    where inserted.[TIME] = '  :  :  '

    update [table] set [time] = STUFF(STUFF([table].[time],3,0,':'),6,0,':')
    from [table]
    join inserted on inserted.id=[table].id
    where inserted.[time] like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

    update [table] set [time] = replace([table].[time], ' ',':')  
    from [table]
    join inserted on inserted.id=[table].id
    where inserted.[time] like '[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]'
go
```

With a proper index on `id` (and supposing that the key is a simple one like an `int` value) this should add almost no time to the insert operation because you are working only with the inserted records, but of course you should test it, specially if inserting the transactions is time critical.